# Custom fonts in widget

Tags: android, android-studio, шрифты, виджет, typeface

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318572/how-to-use-a-custom-typeface-in-a-widget) написано, что чтобы использовать свои шрифты нужно их превращать в картинку с помощью битмапа и вставлять в виджет эту картинку. Вопрос 5-и летней давности, неужели эта проблема так и не решена? Английские шрифты в Android Studio приятные, а вот кириллические шрифты явно не доработаны. Есть ли какой-то способ без костылей свои шрифты внедрить?

Comment: вас интересует использование шрифтов именно в виджетах? тех, что на рабочем столе добавляются? Или вообще `TextView`?

Comment: У виджетов за 5 лет мало что изменилось. Кастомные вьюшки туда не засунуть до сих пор, к примеру.

Comment: Да, именно в виджетах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть способ, выдолжны добавить свои шрифты в папку assets в папке приложения (где хранится папка java и папка ресурсов), если её нету, то создайте в том месте где описано выше.
Пример исползования:

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "tahoma.ttf"));
```

Comment: Этот ответ не может быть правильным, ибо виджет не предоставляет возможности получить любой View напрямую, а только через методы RemoteViews, в котором нет метода setTypeface.